# Can I assign running K2 Processes to another user?

Tags: k2

We are running k2 Blackpearl 4.6, and unfortunately, the K2 experts left the company. I was hired just before the last one turned in his notice. So really, there was no knowledge transfer. So I'm starting from the ground up, and supporting applications that currently use k2 within the solution.

Anyways, now that that's out of the way, one of the users that was assigned a few processes, retired. We need to re-assign any processes that were currently assigned to him to another user. So, a two part question.

Can I assign a process to another user? If so, what will I need to do to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was go into the management console, click on Worklists, then filter by the Destination user. Once that was done, I could check all the items, then select 'Redirect'. The user now sees all the procesess that were assigned to the old user.